Sobolev inequality in the caccioppoli inequality for elliptic systems with superquadratic controllable growth conditions
The line in the proof that confuses me
Hey guys, I stumbled upon this line in the proof for the caccioppoli inequality for elliptic systems with superquadratic controllable growth conditions. The paper in which i found it was this one:https://boundaryvalueproblems.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/1687-2770-2014-88
Anyone know how to get from the first line to the second? Any help is appreciated.

Please provide the details explicitly in the question.
